# Using .isin doesn't match or find a known match within 2 data frames column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 csv files all with the same column name. I am comparing this to a 4th csv file with the same column. This is being done by comparing one csv file against the 4th csv fie (df2) at a time as follows which contains thousands of domains:

I have added in a manual duplicate (domain) for testing and still get the same counts without identifying the duplicate value. I'm sure i am missing something simple here. Thanks in advance for any help.

Method 1 tried:

```
print(df1.colA.isin(df2).values.sum())
print(df3.colA.isin(df2).values.sum())
print(df4.colA.isin(df2).values.sum())
```

Answer i get from above is: 0 which i understand to mean there are no duplicates

Method 2 tried in testing:

```
print(df1.colA.isin(df2).value_counts())
print(~df1.colA.isin(df2).value_counts())
```

Answer i get from above is: False 5294 and -5295 which i understand to mean there are no duplicates

Comment: maybe try df2.colA instead of just df2

Comment: That was it! For some reason i was thinking since it was the only data it would work but, i see now that it needed to be defined. Thanks!